# Low Level programming - MKR Fox1200

Tags: c, assembly

I'm working on a project using this board and wish to do so on a low level ,as in enabling certain registers to enable interrupts etc.
I can't seem to find the correct header files to support programming in this manner (Can't recognise the register names), I've tried using both Atmel Studio and the Arduino IDE but can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What kind of "low level" do you mean?  Why not look up the chip data sheet?  For example: https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/268/atmel-42181-sam-d21_datasheet-1065532.pdf

Comment: If you have installed the MKL Fox 1200 on your computer, then the needed header files are also installed.  They can be rather difficult to find, however the `find` command works well for this job

Comment: I programming from the datasheet, I have the header files imported manually but it doesn't seem to work correctly